# Using a timer changes the error message received from an exiting spawned process

Tags: erlang

In the following why does the error message in one start with "exception exit" but the other starts with "exception error"?

```
1> spawn_link(fun ()-> exit(reason) end).
** exception exit: reason
2> spawn_link(fun ()-> timer:sleep(1), exit(reason) end).
<0.38.0>
** exception error: reason
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is due to a race condition in the Erlang shell implementation. Remember that the shell is also just another Erlang process which reads your command, interprets it, prints the result and loops. When you use spawn_link, your new process gets linked to the shell evaluator process, and when the new process dies, an exit signal gets sent to the shell evaluator process (which also crashes with the same reason and gets restarted). All this should be mostly invisible to the user, but in some cases, implementation details might leak through.

In your first case, the new process is spawned off and starts running but calls exit immediately. In the second case it starts running, goes to sleep for a millisecond, wakes up again, and then exits. That means that the shell evaluator process has had plenty of time to continue, printing the Pid that is the result from spawn_link, and is about to ask for more input when it gets the exit signal from the spawned process. The difference in where the evaluator is currently at causes the exit reason to be printed differently (somehow). Technically, I'd say that it's a bug.

To demonstrate further:

```
1> spawn_link(fun ()-> timer:sleep(1), exit(reason) end), timer:sleep(1).
** exception exit: reason
```

Here, by keeping the interpretation code running a bit longer by sleeping for a millisecond after spawning the new process, we get the original behaviour back.

Answer (score 2):

here is the answer [errors-and-processes](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/errors-and-processes)

```
1> link(spawn(fun() -> exit(reason) end)).
** exception exit: reason
2> link(spawn(fun() -> timer:sleep(1000), exit(reason) end)).
true
** exception error: reason
```

exception exit - when process terminated before link

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: The question is using spawn_link, which does the spawn and link atomically, so the link(spawn(...)) race condition is not what happens in this case.